# How can i upload and use a .CSS, .js, and some audio files on my html project? (so that all thats needed is the HTML file)

Tags: html, external

I have some HTML that grabs a .CSS and a .js from my windows computer, how do I change this to grab it from online? (for example upload it to google drive then grab it from their, or something) I'm trying to make it so all the user needs is the HTML file.

(I'm new to HTML) so the above is the current external libraries/files that I have linked in my HTML, I would like to upload them somewhere online and access all of them online and only need the HTML to run the project.

Comment: If you had AWS' S3 storage, you could use a URL from them for the CSS and JS files. I don't think you can use Google Drive for this, but I could be wrong

Comment: CSS and JS can be inlined, so you don't need any request at all. For media it's not that easy but can be done using data-urls

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about using Google Drive, but you can upload the files to a number of places around the web.

Once you have them uploaded all you need to do is to add the URLs for where they are located in place of the path that they are stored on your local disk in your html file and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that uploading to google drive and accessing files there will work, but you can try uploading to a web host and accessing them from there. After you've uploaded your files, change your code slightly so `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">` turns into `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/main.css">`. Do the same for your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you are looking for is a CDN(Content Delivery Network). You can store all your CSS, fonts, images and js files on this CDN and link them via URL in your HTML file.

Here are some free CDNs available

Netlify - https://www.netlify.com/

Hostry - https://hostry.com/products/cdn/

JSDELIVR -https://www.jsdelivr.com/

Cloudflare - https://www.cloudflare.com/en-in/#what-is-cloudflare